# How to make the load function of JavaFX's WebEngine load a local URL?

Tags: webview, javafx

Currently I have a basic WebView set up with JavaFX and a html file that I need to load in my local home folder. However, when I set a URL object to the home folder and try to load that URL using the WebEngine's load function, the page does not load. The page content.html is perfectly fine. Here is my code:

```
String contentURL = new URL("file://" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/content.html").toExternalForm();
webEngine.load(contentURL);
System.out.println(contentURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an extra slash to file protocol; `"file:///"`. For more info follow [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).